# Website mobile Chrome sizing is not correct when source is QR code or hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, mobile-chrome

This issue only seems to occur in mobile Chrome (iOS, android untested) but not in mobile Safari or mobile Opera.

When going to the website on mobile by typing in the URL directly, the objects correctly scale to the size of the screen:

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hl75.jpg) and [Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6amK.jpg)

When the user is directed to the link from a QR code or a hyperlink though on mobile chrome (iOS, android is still untested), the website vertical scaling looks wrong:

[Portrait - vertical scale is too long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpTof.jpg)

It visually looks to me that when coming from a QR code or hyperlink on chrome mobile, the browser is setting the vertical scale without taking into account the navbars.

Here is my html and CSS below.  I am happy adding a JavaScript timeout which rescales somehow if necessary a second or two after load?

## HTML and CSS

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#borderCtl {
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    
    padding: 30px 50px;
}

.subtitle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid white 1px;
  font-size: 3.2vw;
}

#rotationRequest {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3.2vh;
}
 


 


@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    #rotationRequest {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    div.subtitle, div.borderCtl {
        display: none;
    }
    
    

}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    #rotationRequest {
        display: none;
    }
    div.subtitle {
        display: flex;      
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <!-- removed javascript files for stackoverflow purposes, should not effect anything -->
    
</head>

<body >
        <div id="rotationRequest">
            <div>Please rotate your device!</div>
            <img id="rotateImage" src="img/mobile-rotate.svg" width="80%">
        </div>
        
        <div id="borderCtl">
            <div class="subtitle">
                <div id="topLine">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what's supposed to be happening in portrait mode and in landscape mode

Comment: @SidNutthi Compare the text in the portrait image where the scale is correct to the portrait image where the scale is incorrect.  You can see that the text is larger.  The font size is being set in terms of `vh`.  I'm not sure why visiting from a QR code results in a different `vh` calculation.  I guess I could set it in terms of `vw` which hopefully would not vary depending on source.